# scipy.optimize.curve_fit for logistic function

Tags: scipy, logistic-regression, scipy-optimize

I am trying to draw a logistic function with Jupyter Notebook. I can plot it nicely but the logistic function using scipy.optimize.curve_fit does not work. It returns straight line coordinates.

How can I plot the logistic regression line?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/shinokada/76070a0927fa1fac01eeaed298757a26/raw/2707a1bd7cba80613a01a2026abeb9f587dbaee5/logisticdata.csv')

x=df.T.iloc[0]
y=df.T.iloc[1]

def logifunc(x,l,c,k):
    return l / (1 + c*np.exp(-k*x))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x, y, p0=[-150,1,1])
print(*popt)

x_data = np.linspace(170,205,num=100)
print(logifunc(x_data, *popt))

plt.scatter(x,y,label='Logistic function')
plt.plot(x_data, logifunc(x_data, *popt), 'r-',label='Fitted function')

plt.title("Logistic")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.xlim(170,210)
plt.ylim(-210,-160)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation you chose for logistic function is not ideal for your data set. It assumes the minimum value for your data is zero and that the sigmoid midpoint is also zero, neither of which is the true here.

If you use the equation from the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) and add an offset `off` since your data varies between -205 and -165 approx:

```
def logifunc(x,A,x0,k,off):
    return A / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))+off
```

I switched `l` for `A` because `A` now represents the difference between your data max and min values (the amplitude). With reasonable starting parameters:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(logifunc, x, y, p0=[50,185,0.1,-222])
plt.scatter(x,y,label='Logistic function')
plt.plot(x_data, logifunc(x_data, *popt), 'r-',label='Fitted function')
plt.legend()
```

[image: data and fit]

```
print(popt)
[  37.07  187.83    0.19 -203.56]
```